# Changing font and background colors in RMarkdown when printing a list

Tags: list, r-markdown, kable

I am trying to print a list of data frames using the kable package and I am unable to change the colors or stylings of the tables. I can successfully print the list using the following code but the row stripes red command and the font color green command is not working.  Is this possible to change using this method?

```
{r, results = "asis", echo = FALSE}
df1 = data.frame(c1 = rep(5, 5), c2 = rep(3, 5))

df2 = data.frame(c1 = rep(5, 10), c2 = rep(3, 10))

l = list(df1, df2)

## tables
for(i in seq_along(l)) {
  print(
      kable(l[[i]], format = "latex", longtable = TRUE, row.names = NA, col.names = NULL) %>%
        kable_styling(font_size = 7, latex_options = "repeat_header", full_width = TRUE, stripe_color =  "red") %>%
row_spec(1, color= "green")
  )
}
```